# Reactjs submit multiple forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is an example of how the rendering part of my FormHandler.js looks like:

```
return (
  <div>
    <CustomForm1 data={ testProps1 }/>
    <CustomForm2 data={ testProps2 }/>
  </div>
)
```

The CustomForms are two form components I have created and each have their own "get" and "post" requests to the backend (django in this case).

Would it be possible to:

Firstly, create a button in FormHanlder.js to submit the values of the customform components using their respective "post" functions

And secondly, extract the values inputed in each CustomForm and handle them in CustomForms.js before submitting. For example, assuming this is in CustomForm1.js:

```
<input name="customField" />
```

Maybe I could use something like:

```
let fieldValue = CustomForm1.customField.value;
```

From a function inside FormHandler.js, so that I can make some extra computation before submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can't go from child to parent (bottom up), you can always go top down from parent to child using state propagation. Declare a state variable and it's change handler inside FormHandler.js and pass it as a prop to the Custom Form Component.
Let's say you need 1 extra field as in CustomForm1. The code should look something like this:

Inside FormHandler.js (Assuming you are using functional components)

```
function FormHandler() {
    const [customFieldForForm1, setCustomFieldForForm1] = React.useState("");
    // inside your submit handler you can easily use this customFieldForForm1 value
    ...
    return (
        <div>
            <CustomForm1 data={testProps1} customField={customFieldForForm1} onCustomFieldChange={setCustomFieldForForm1} />
            <CustomForm2 data={testProps2} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

inside CustomForm1.js

```
function CustomForm1(props) {
    return (
        <form ...>
            ...
            <input name="customField" value={props.customField} onChange={props.onCustomFieldChange} />
            ...
        </form>
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I can definitely make this work the way I want